# XML property is required depending on the attribute value of the parent property in WSDL

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl, xsd-validation

Maybe my question is duplicate but I couldn't find anything similar to it.

I have the following WSDL fragment:

```
<xs:complexType name="CompanyName">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ShortName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="language" type="tax:LanguageType" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where the LanguagType is an enumeration like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="LanguageType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Language1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Language2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Language3" />
        ...
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As soon as the `Language` attribute in `CompanyName` is set to *"Language1"*, the `ShortName` child element should be required in parent `CompanyName`.

**QUESTION:** How can I toggle `minOccurs="0"` attribute in `ShortName` element depending on the value of `Language` attribute in `CompanyName` or how to achieve what I have described, so that xsd validation works here?.

Many thanks.

Comment: I see this has a ‘java’ tag.  Are you looking for an answer written in Java code, or a purely XML schema solution?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a purely XML schema solution, I just put the "Java" tag, because eventually I need to use the XML in Java :)